# $scope.$watch with non existing variable as value

Tags: angularjs

I've been trying to understand $watch function on $scope object. This looks pretty straight forward but the thing that I don't understand is why (on page load) listener function is being executed when I pass a non existing $scope object variable in value function.

```
$scope.$watch ('nonExistingVariableIdentifier', function () { console.log('Variable value changed'); });
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The watch runs when it is created.

The full use of a $watch is:

```
$scope.$watch("nonExistantVariable", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue == oldValue) {
        // First run
    }
    else {
        // After First run
    }
})
```

This is the correct way to differentiate between the initialization and an actual change.

> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when the result of watchExpression didn't change. To detect this scenario within the listener fn, you can compare the newVal and oldVal. If these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due to initialization.

From the Angular JS Docs for $watch - [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)